# Würde die konsequente Verwendung des Genitivs nach Präpositionen (theoretisch) selbst für Muttersprachler akzeptabel klingen?

Tags: preposition, genitive, style

Ich werde von des ersten Satzes an versuchen, nach Präpositionen stets den Genitiv zu verwenden.

Es ist ja nicht erst seit eines Bestsellers eines gewissen Sprachentertainers so, dass in des Bildungsbürgertums die Annahme gilt, der edle und schützenswerte Genitiv werde von des minderwertigen Dativs zunehmend bedroht. So setzte sich dank Dafürhaltens von "Sprachwahrer" nach bestimmter Präpositionen wie "wegen" oder "trotz" der Genitiv als der zu folgende Kasus durch – auch, wenn es gute Argumente gegen einer solcher Entwicklung gibt.
Da stellt sich mir die Frage: Könnte man, wenn der Genitiv doch so schön ist, diese Entwicklung weiter fördern, indem man langsam für immer mehrer Präpositionen den Genitiv vorsieht? Das Russische ist uns in dieser Hinsicht bereits voraus: Präp. wie "gegen", "für", "aus", "von", "ab", "nach", "vor" verlangen dort den Genitiv.

Auf den ersten Blick sagt uns unser geschultes Sprachgefühl, dass viele Stellen dieses kurzen Textes schlichtweg falsch sind. Nach kurzen Innehaltens bei jeden Falles kann ich mir/meiner jedoch vorstellen, dass diese Fälle, hätte sich die Sprache nur leicht anders entwickelt, als gut und richtig gelten würden. Dem Genitiv haftet einfach der "Charme" der Amtssprache an und gilt als im Zweifelsfall stets zu bevorzugen.

Mir ist bewusst, dass ernsthafte Grammatiker und Sprachkundige ihre guten Argumente für bzw. gegen der Verwendung bestimmter Kasus haben. Doch wie sieht es mit des Volksmundes des Bildungsbürgertums, der Medien und weiterer Komplizen aus? Wenn man den Dativ nach "trotz" oder "dank" in des Bereichs des Dialektalen verbannen konnte, warum sollte das, rein hypothetisch, nicht auch mit weiterer Präpositionen möglich sein (einiger weiterer Sicks bedürfte es dafür natürlich schon).

Ich bin gespannt auf eurer Meinung.

Comment: Stirbt der Genitiv überhaupt aus? Ich behaupte: Nein. Genau wie der Konjunktiv nicht ausstirbt, weil dessen Anwendung den Bildungsbürger vom einfachen Volk absetzt. Nebenwirkung: Es wird der Genitiv auch dort reingesemmelt, wo er gar nicht reingehört.

Comment: Ich denke auch nicht, dass er ausstirbt. Neben Präpositionen gibt es noch so viele andere Anwendungen.

Comment: Der Mensch gewöhnt sich an allem.

Comment: An aller vielleicht nicht, aber doch an vieler. Und ich meine, an des Genitivs in dauernder Verwendung nach der Präpositionen gewöhnte man sich leicht. Auf aller Fälle wäre es eines Versuches wert.

Answer (score 6):

Die Frage kann nicht sein, ob statt des Dativs auch der Genitiv *hätte akzeptabel werden und klingen können*. Sicher hätte es so kommen können - konkrete Oberflächenformen sind arbiträr, d.h. sie sind in ihrer jetzigen Form gerechtfertigt im wesentlichen durch die gegenseitige übereinkunft, sie so und nicht anders zu verwenden, und nicht durch irgendwelche intrinsischen Vorzüge.

Der wesentliche Punkt ist: könnte eine Sprache funktionieren, wenn alle Präpositionen *den gleichen Kasus* regieren? Nun, in vielen Sprachen gibt es gar keine Oberflächenkasus und trotzdem Präpositionen. Es ist also nicht rundheraus unmöglich. Die Frage muß also sein: könnte *der Rest* des Deutschen *so wie jetzt* funktionieren, wenn der regierte Kasus von Präpositionen nicht mehr als Ausdrucksmittel existierte?

Man könnte zum Beispiel nicht mehr unterscheiden zwischen "über dem See" und über den See", es würden sich also höchstwahrscheinlich andere Anzeiger für Ort vs. Richtung herausbilden. Linguisten können sicher viele weitere 
Folgen nennen. Die Antwort ist also: nicht ohne unabsehbare weitere Folgen für das Gefüge der Sprache insgesamt.

Answer (score 1):

Wenn ich die Frage richtig verstehe, lautet sie **eigentlich**:

> Beobachtungen zeigen, dass der Genitiv langsam ausstirbt und langfristig wohl gar nicht mehr verwendet wird.
>
> Wäre auch das Szenario denkbar, dass ein anderer der drei Fälle ausstirbt und der Genitiv erhalten bleibt?

Meiner Meinung nach: Nein.

Ich denke, dass der Grund für das Verschwinden des Genitivs der folgende ist:

Die Bildung des Genitivs ist komplizierter als die der anderen Fälle (Anhängen von "-s", "-es" oder aber auch nicht), was dessen Verwendung komplizierter macht.

Kleine Kinder werden daher versuchen, diesen Fall zu vermeiden - z.B. in dem das Wort "von" eingefügt und der Dativ verwendet wird.

Da Menschen prinzipiell faul sind, werden sie sich auch im höheren Alter davor "drücken", die etwas kompliziertere Bildung des Genitivs zu erlernen.

Wieso auch?

Die Sprache verändert sich mit der Zeit. Das Deutsch zu Goethes Zeiten unterschied sich stark vom heutigen. Was sollte so schlecht daran sein, wenn die deutsche Sprache im Jahre 2100 nur drei Fälle kennt?

Bei den anderen drei Fällen gibt es im Deutschen diese Schwierigkeit nicht.

> Das Russische ...

Ich gehe davon aus, dass in Sprachen, in denen die Bildung des Genitivs nicht schwerer ist als die der anderen Formen, dieses Phänomen auch nicht auftritt.

Comment: Meine Frage war weniger ein Blick in die Glaskugel, als ein Gedankenspiel.

Comment: Ich glaube übrigens nicht, dass der Genitiv ausstirbt oder weniger verwendet wird. Das Gegenteil ist der Fall, was ja die Fälle von wegen, trotz oder dank zeigen. Jeder, der etwas auf sich hält, wird dort den Genitiv verwenden, ob das linguistisch sinnvoll ist oder nicht. Übrigens glaube ich, dass Goethe auch "wegen dem" sagte, sowie einige weitere Audrücke, bei denen dem typischen hanseatischen Bildungsbürger der Monokel in den Schwarztee fällt.

Comment: @wegendem Dass es sich beim Aussterben des Dativ um ein Gedankenspiel handelt, habe ich schon verstanden. Gerade bei Personen mit weniger Bildung wird der Genitiv garantiert nicht aussterben, weil bei diesen Personen bereits heute nur noch die Fälle Nominativ, Dativ und Akkusativ existieren. Was schon ausgestorben ist, kann nicht ein zweites Mal aussterben. Und auch gebildetere Personen verwenden den Genitiv nur selten bis gar nicht, wenn sie sich im Alltag unterhalten. Irgendwann müssen die offiziellen Regeln jeder Sprache an die tatsächliche Verwendung angepasst werden und nicht umgekehrt.

Comment: Der Dativ ist oft genau so schwer (oder leicht) zu bilden wie der Genitiv. Die *Bildung* der Fälle ist für Muttersprachler auch typischerweise nicht das Problem, da dieser Vorgang unbewusst im Gehirn vonstattengeht (und er folgt den im Sprachzentrum verankerten grammatikalischen Regeln, die schwer zu beschreiben sind). Ein »Problem« (wenn man es so bezeichnen möchte) ist höchstens, dass die Umgangssprache Alternativen vorschlägt, die als weniger schicklich gelten.